# Can't understand OpenMP sections

Tags: c, openmp

I have this OpenMP code which use sections

```
    #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(8)
    {
        printf_s("Allo from thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        #pragma omp section
        printf_s("Bello from thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        #pragma omp section
        printf_s( "Cello from thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
```

I get different sorts of outputs. Sometimes only the thread 0 prints all the three lines and sometimes different threads do it. I don't understand this, should't the three lines always get printed from three different threads?

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP does not guarantee the behaviour you expect.  The sections construct guarantees (at least, the specification of the construct guarantees, implementations might be broken) that each section is executed by one (and only one) thread.  It does not guarantee that each section is executed by a different thread.

At the level you observe your program is non-deterministic, as you have observed.  This is not unusual for parallel programs and a lesson to bear in mind; there are situations where it is the programmer's responsibility to order the execution of segments of code if it is necessary to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Open MP guarantees that each section will be executed by a different thread to make concurrent calculations.

Your first statement can be executed by any of the 8 threads created, but the 2nd and the 3rd print statements will be executed by any two different threads of the 8 threads made. If it does not happen, put the 1st statement under the pragma section directive. Then all three statements will be executed by different threads.

Comment: I don't think that this answer is correct.  I think that OpenMP only requires that each section be executed by only one thread, not that each section be executed by a different thread.  How would OpenMP guarantee that behaviour with 12 sections and only 4 threads ?